# How to kepp trailing zero from BigDecimals with Zero part in Json via Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

In my JAVA Application, the database values (BigDecimals) 11.0 and 22.5345 are printed to json an a Rest Service like:

```
{
  "value1" : 11,
  "value2" : 22.5345
}
```

but I like to have them printed like this:

```
{
  "value1" : 11.0,
  "value2" : 22.5345
}
```

Using antoations like:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER_FLOAT)
```

or
`@JsonSerialize(using = PaddedSerializer.class)` with an own serializer like

```
public class PaddedSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BigDecimal> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(BigDecimal value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException {
        if (value.scale() == 0) {
            jgen.writeString(value.setScale(1).toPlainString());
        } else {
            jgen.writeString(value.toPlainString());
        }
    }
}
```

only gives:

```
{
  "value1" : "11.0",
  "value2" : "22.5345"
}
```

the values as strings. Using these json in a php-client, transforming into an object with value1 and value2 defined as double with standard setters, results in an exception, because of the string representation.
Example:

```
class MeasurementResponseModel 
{
  /**
   * @var float|null
   */
  public $value1;
  /**
   * @param float|null $value1
   */
  public function setValue1(?float $value1): void
  {
      $this->value1= $value1;
  }
}
```

A terrible fix would be to use on the php-client site:

```
class MeasurementResponseModel 
{
  /**
   * @var float|null
   */
  public $value1;
  /**
   * @param string|null $value1
   */
  public function setValue1(?string $value1): void
  {
      $this->value1= floatval($value1);
  }
}
```

together with an fomratted string output in the java rest client, which looks very ugly.

I do not understand, why all trailing zeros are stripped in the jackson part of the java rest service for numbers and there is no possibility to print 11 als 11.0 in the json, because 11 in json is always interpreted as integer and only a 11.0 would be interpreted as double.

So is there any way to print numbers without a fractional part as x.0 in the json output of the rest service - and I mean not to print it as as formatted string?

Comment: So, you write `jgen.writeString(value.setScale(1).toPlainString());` and wonder why you indeed get strings?

Comment: you explicitly convert the values to String and then explicitly use `writeString`. Why?

Comment: Note that floating point numbers (as in the json) have no precision. 11.0 == 11.000 and are prone to approximation errors. And `new BigDecimal(11.0)` loses its precision ("scale") too. Only `new BigDecimal("11.0")` is both exact and with a scale of 1.